# vagrant Failed writing body (0 != 16384)

Tags: windows, vagrant

```
vagrant init https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-i386-vagrant-disk1.box

vagrant up
```

Выходит ошибка

```
    Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-i386-vagrant-disk1.box' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> default: Adding box 'https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-i386-vagrant-disk1.box' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-i386-vagrant-disk1.box
    default: Progress: 0% (Rate: 0Warning:/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Failed writing body (0 != 16384)
```

По ссылке файл доступен, почему пишет ошибку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Была такая-же проблема из-за русских символов в пути к папке, где выполнялаcь vagrant up.
Еще одна возможная причина: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2056